# LuaTeX: tex-text at 10 pt not loadable

Tags: errors, luatex, fontspec, font-encodings

I am trying to use LuaTeX with Linux Biolinum. It works fine with XeLaTeX, but when I'm running LuaLaTex, it gives me the following error:

> ! Font \EU1/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text at 10pt not loadable:
>   metric data not found or bad.

This error is found in the fontenc.sty on line 100. 
I am using Texlive 2011 on Ubuntu 10.04, this is my example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[lutf8x]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Biolinum}
\begin{document}
  Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: AFAIK Biolinum is the default sf with package [libertine](http://ctan.org/pkg/libertine). This package may be used with latex+dvips, pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex.

Comment: The manual of luainputenc recommends to use the package only, if you are not using utf8 encoding for input and if you are using a 8 bit font. Biolinum is a unicode font. So you may - and maybe should - use utf8 input without loading luainputenc.

Comment: What happens if you omit the `luainputenc` package?

Comment: You can take at the filename cache `less \`kpsexpand $TEXMFVAR\`/luatex-cache/generic/names/otfl-names.lua` and find out about the font names.

Comment: And I am a bit confused about the error message. Is this really the error message for the file you posted in your question? Can you give more information?

Comment: Shame on me! I've had two different versions of TeX Live installed (2009 and 2011). After cleaning up this mess and reinstalling TeX Live 2011, everything works fine.

Comment: Based on @Greg's comment, I'd suggest this is 'too localized' - do others agree?

Comment: @JosephWright I disagree. I'm having the same problem right now and having closed it makes it more difficult to find an answer.

Comment: @jonallard As stated, the OP here had a particular issue with his system. Please post a new question detailing your issue.

Comment: @Joseph It is the same issue. I doubt reposting the same question would be very useful for the community...

Comment: @Greg try running luaotfload-tool --update, this fixed a similar problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your error message says `! Font \EU1/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]`. `EU1` is the encoding used by fontspec for xelatex. And the syntax with the `[--]`-braces around the font is xelatex syntax. So it looks as if fontspec for some reason is loading xelatex support files and then chokes over the wrong syntax. Which version of fontspec are you using? Did you check the log if perhaps an old version is used?

Addition: And I also advice against the use of luainputenc. It should be used only if really needed and then carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The font is called `Linux Biolinum O`. This is what you can do:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[lutf8x]{luainputenc}
\setmainfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

Don't use `luainputenc` if you can avoid it. And load `fontspec` before this package, since it defines the `EU2` encoding (a transparent unicode "encoding").

Comment: Unfortunately, the error remains the same (I've tried Oh and Zero). Is there a special Lua-version of fontenc, or something?

Comment: AFAIK the font name depends on the OS.

Comment: @Schweinebacke the fonts in the texlive tree should have the same name, AFAIK

Comment: @Patrick: AFAIK at least at Windows XP the font names are "Linux Libertine" and "Linux Biolinum" without the "O" at least using MiKTeX.

Comment: @Schweinebacke No, the above test file also runs on Windows XP (using TeXlive 2011). The difference is (as I've heard) that the "O" fonts are the OpenType fonts.

Comment: MiKTeX is not TeX Live. Some weeks ago I've tried to move a file from TeX Live at Linux to MiKTeX at Windows XP and have to remove the "O". But maybe the installation was broken, it was not my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}\sffamily
Text ÄÖÜ
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
Text ÄÖÜ
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
Text ÄÖÜ
\end{document}
```

All of them worked very well with new net installation of [TeX Live 2011](http://www.tug.org/texlive) and lualatex, if the test files are utf8 encoded. So maybe you should update or reinstall your TeX Live.